# Show proof technique

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Given $\Gamma^n := \{\phi_{i} \rightarrow \phi_{i+1} | 1 \le i \le n-1  \} \bigcup \{\phi_{n} \rightarrow \phi_{1}\}$ .

I want to show that $ \Gamma ^ {n} \vDash \{\phi_{i} \leftrightarrow \phi_{j} |  1 \le i,j \le n \}$ through induction. I started the induction step the follwoing way:

$$ \Gamma ^ {n+1} = \{\phi_{i} \rightarrow \phi_{i+1} | 1 \le i \le n \} \bigcup \{\phi_{n+1} \rightarrow \phi_{1}\} = \{\phi_{i} \rightarrow \phi_{i+1} | 1 \le i \le n-1 \} \bigcup \{\phi_{n} \rightarrow \phi_{1}\}\bigcup \{\phi_{n} \rightarrow \phi_{n+1}\} \bigcap \lnot\{\phi_{n} \rightarrow \phi_{1}\} \bigcup \{\phi_{n+1} \rightarrow \phi_{1}\}$$

I am not sure how I could proceed though. I also should use the idempotency and monotonicity of the deductive closure $Cn(.)$ somehow. But I am pretty much stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the induction step, you first need to show $\phi_n\rightarrow \phi_1$. In your proof you directly used it but that would be incorrect you have to prove it although the proof is simple: $\phi_n\rightarrow \phi_{n+1}$ and $\phi_{n+1}\rightarrow \phi_1$ implies $\phi_n\rightarrow \phi_1$.

Now we can use our induction hypothesis to conclude that $\phi_i \leftrightarrow \phi_j$ for all $1\leq i,j\leq n$. Then what you need to show is for all $1\leq i\leq n$ we have $\phi_{n+1}\leftrightarrow\phi_i$.

This is also easy as $\phi_i\leftrightarrow\phi_n\rightarrow\phi_{n+1}$ and $\phi_{n+1}\rightarrow\phi_1\leftrightarrow\phi_i$.

From this we have $\phi_i \leftrightarrow \phi_j$ for all $1\leq i,j\leq n+1$ and we are done.

Comment: I used it in my inductiove step because of the induction hypothesis though.

Comment: You cannot apply the induction hypothesis unless you construct a subset of the n+1 case that satisfy the structure of the n case.

Comment: So the equation in the n+1 case isn't valid?

Comment: Because I feel that I constructed the n+1 case with the help of the n case which is the point of induction I thought.

Comment: Not really. The induction hypothesis does not give you new definition of your structure; when you construct $n+1$ case you have to use the definition, which is the cycle from $\phi_1,\phi_2,...$ to $\phi_{n+1}$ and back to $\phi_1$. You need to show a subcycle of $n$ is contained in this "larger" cycle in order to apply the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much.